# Calculation of a Jacobian determinant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, determinant, jacobian

I want to calculate the Jacobian determinant of the function$$
f(x,z_1, \ldots, z_{n-1}) =
x (z_1, \ldots, z_{n-1},1 - z_1 - \ldots - z_{n-1}),
$$
i.e.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 z_1 & x & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
 z_2 & 0 & x & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
 z_3 & 0 & 0 & x & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots &  &  & \ddots & \ddots& 0 \\
 z_{n-1} & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & x \\
 1- z_1 - \ldots - z_{n-1} & -x & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & -x 
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
For $n=2$ I get $-x = (-x)^1$ and for $n=3$ I get $x^2 = (-x)^2$. So my guess for the $n$-dimensional case ($n$ variables) would be $(-x)^{n-1}$. How can I formally calculate the determinant? I tried to use Laplace's formula for the first row, but I couldn't calculate the determinant of the two minors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

adding the first $n-1$ rows to the last one, the determinant becomes really simple.

Comment: Yes. It's really simple !